# jQuery Card Switching Active Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The website I'm currently working on is here (map section):
http://vtx.canny-creative.com/

I'm currently facing two problems:

1. The 'active' class adds to the .location-card on the left. But I also need the corresponding .dot on the right hand side to have 'active' added to it. Which I can do. However...
2. What I can't do, is get the "first loaded/visible" DIVs, "selected dot", to have 'active' applied. So the active will only apply on click, rather than "on load" and then "on click" as I cycle through them.

```js
$('a.dot').on('click tap', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.card').css('z-index', '0');
  $('.card.active').css('z-index', '2');
  $('.card').removeClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.where-we-operate .card-container {
  position: relative;
  .card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .active {
    z-index: 4 !important;
    animation: foo 0.5s ease 1;
  }
}

.where-we-operate .map-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="where-we-operate">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-margin-x">
      <div class="large-6 cell card-container">
        <div id="card1" class="location-tile card">
          Card Info Here
        </div>
        <div id="card2" class="location-tile card">
          Card Info Here
        </div>
        <div id="card3" class="location-tile card">
          Card Info Here
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 cell map-container">
        <a href="#card1" class="dot london"></a>
        <a href="#card2" class="dot coventry"></a>
        <a href="#card3" class="dot south-shields"></a>
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/vortex/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/uk-map.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've created something using the jQuery fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/xc8ebuf4/

Comment: Hi, questions asking for debugging help (or "why isn't my code doing X?") need to include a [mcve] in the question itself; linking to a code sandbox like JSFiddle alone is not adequate.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the code I'm working with into my post. Does that suffice?

Comment: That looks like pretty comprehensive markup, but I notice your JSFiddle has CSS as well, and the HTML is more minimal than what you just added to your question. Is the markup you just added all required, or just the markup from the Fiddle? Likewise, if the CSS in the Fiddle is required to reproduce the problem, it should be added to the question as well.

Comment: Sorry again. I've filtered down the HTML to the bare necessities, and added what I'd imagine is the only required CSS. However, I actually doubt that makes a difference to the problem.

Comment: Can't you just add the `active` class in your HTML to the elements that should have the class on pageload?

Comment: *face palm* - yes, yes I could. Must've been a long day! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm officially answering this mainly because I can't stand unanswered questions, then again, it might be helpful to those on an off-day or those just starting out.*

You can simply add the `active` class in your HTML to the elements that should have the class on pageload:

```
<div id="card1" class="location-tile card active">
```

Another option is to add the `active` class with jQuery either before or after your event-handler:

```
$('#card1').addClass('active');
```